# Retrieve Specific Text from String where Search String Exists and Not Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got the following code. It returns the correct result for the first two test strings, where it should return the text between the two ****.

The 3rd string returns " abcd two two ****" rather than " abcd two two "
The 4th string returns "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Any ideas?

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '**** mary had a little lamb****' AS TestString UNION ALL
    SELECT '**** humpy dumpty had a great fall**** All the king''s horses and all the king''s men' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bla **** abcd two two **** dfdfdfd' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'test'
)
SELECT
    TestString,
    SUBSTRING(TestString,
              CHARINDEX('****', TestString) + 4,
              CHARINDEX('****', TestString, CHARINDEX('****', TestString) + 1) - 5) AS contents
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search terms are four asterisks.  This approach uses CHARINDEX, once forwards to find the first set, and then with REVERSE to find the last occurrence.

```
;WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '**** mary had a little lamb****' AS TestString UNION ALL
    SELECT '**** humpy dumpty had a great fall**** All the king''s horses and all the king''s men' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bla **** abcd two two **** dfdfdfd' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'test'
)
SELECT
    TestString,
    trim(case when cx.cndx=4 then TestString 
        else substring(TestString, cx.cndx, (cx.len_t-cx.cndx)-cx.rndx-2) end) MiddleString
FROM yourTable
     cross apply
     (select len(TestString) len_t,
             charindex('****', TestString)+4 cndx,
             charindex('****', reverse(TestString)) rndx) cx;
```

Output

```
TestString                              MiddleString
**** mary had a little lamb****         mary had a little lamb
**** humpy [shortened] fall**** All...  humpy dumpty had a great fall
bla **** abcd two two **** dfdfdfd      abcd two two 
test                                    test
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `PATINDEX()` and `CHARINDEX()` as the following:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '**** mary had a little lamb****' AS TestString UNION ALL
    SELECT '**** humpy dumpty had a great fall**** All the king''s horses and all the king''s men' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bla **** abcd two two **** dfdfdfd' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'test'
)
SELECT TestString, SUBSTRING(TestString, T.PIX, NULLIF(TT.CIX, 0) - T.PIX)
FROM YourTable YT CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES
  (
    PATINDEX('%****%', TestString) + 5
  )
) T(PIX) CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES
  (
    CHARINDEX('*', TestString, T.PIX)
  )
) TT(CIX);
```

Here is a [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5eaa5e252a06e8caa2fafd1250bf3e2d)